# Error while executing makefile in c

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to create one makefile using c. For that I have main.c,add.c,minus.c,print.c and Functions.h header file.In this list other than main.c add files have simple add function, subtract function and print function. That Functions.h file have declarations for all functions.

> my problem is I have written one makefile. In that I'm trying to redirect the object files into one directory. When I execute the makefile. It throws an error like

make: *** No rule to make target `/%.c', needed by`obj'.  Stop

.
Make file  has the lines

```
 CFLAG :=-Wall -g
    CC := gcc
    INCLUDE:=-I include
    OBJDIR:=obj
    SRCDIR:=src
    TARGET:=bin/Math

CFILES:=$(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJECTS:=$(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(CFILES))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o:$(SRCDIR)/%.c
        @$(CC) -c $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $< $(CFLAG) 


(TARGET):$(OBJECTS) 
        @$(CC) $(CFLAG) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

.PHONY : clean
clean :
 -rm  -f $(OBJDIR)/*.o
```

Please help me guys....

Comment: You have a typo.

Comment: typo means what?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You forgot the `$` in front of `$(TARGET):$(OBJECTS)`, which would cause problems, but it wouldn't create the issue you described.  What you described sounds like you have a hidden character in your `$(OBJDIR)/%.o:$(SRCDIR)/%.c` rule.    I would suggest erasing that line, and retyping it manually to see if it gets rid of the problem.  (also retype the OBJDIR and SRCDIR definitions).

Comment: BTW, I just cut and paste it on my local machine (replacing the spaces with tabs, and fixing the `$` issue), and it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you so much its working.....